# Assign higher priority to PPA

Tags: apt, ppa, repository

I'm trying to figure out how to assign higher priority to one PPA over another PPA. I had a look on bunch of the answers on this forum but none of them solves my problem.

We have two PPA sources on some of our servers which we stick into separate files in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` . Some of these repos provide same packages (in terms of names) but different versions and possibly different binaries. Is there a way how we can PRIORITISE one repo over another ?

I read **apt_preferences** tutorial but it could not be more obscure and didn't find the answers for my question. Here is the situation. WE have the following sources:

```
$ ls -l /etc/apt/sources.list.d 
total 12
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 66 Jan  2 16:50 nginx-source.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 84 Jan  2 16:49 ruby-ng-experimental-source.list
```

where `nginx-source.list` content is:

```
deb     http://ppa.launchpad.net/nginx/stable/ubuntu precise main
```

and `ruby-ng-experimental-source.list` content is:

```
deb     http://ppa.launchpad.net/brightbox/ruby-ng-experimental/ubuntu precise main
```

Both of these sources provide nginx-full package of different versions etc.
When I list the priorities ruby-ng-experimental-source.list is on top of output hence nginx-full is installed from that repo:

```
$ apt-cache policy nginx-full                                 
nginx-full:
  Installed: 1:1.2.3-1~38~precise1
  Candidate: 1:1.2.6-1~43~precise1
  Version table:
     1:1.2.6-1~43~precise1 0
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/brightbox/ruby-ng-experimental/ubuntu/ precise/main amd64 Packages
 *** 1:1.2.3-1~38~precise1 0
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     1.4.1-1ppa0~precise 0
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/nginx/stable/ubuntu/ precise/main amd64 Packages
     1.1.19-1ubuntu0.1 0
        500 http://mirror.rackspace.co.uk/ubuntu/ precise-updates/universe amd64 Packages
     1.1.19-1 0
        500 http://mirror.rackspace.co.uk/ubuntu/ precise/universe amd64 Packages
```

How do I prioritize repo listed in nginx-source.list over the one which is on top of the list now ? I tried something like this:

```
$ cat /etc/apt/preferences
Package: nginx-full
Pin: origin http://ppa.launchpad.net/nginx/stable/ubuntu
Pin-Priority: 1000

Package: nginx-full
Pin: origin http://ppa.launchpad.net/brightbox/ruby-ng-experimental/ubuntu
Pin-Priority: 100
```

But that has changed priorities of both sources to the same number - or something like that ? So this has NOT changed the priorities and nginx-full is still being installed form the brightbox PPA

```
$ apt-cache policy nginx-full  
nginx-full:
  Installed: 1:1.2.3-1~38~precise1
  Candidate: 1:1.2.6-1~43~precise1
  Package pin: (not found)
  Version table:
     1:1.2.6-1~43~precise1 1000
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/brightbox/ruby-ng-experimental/ubuntu/ precise/main amd64 Packages
 *** 1:1.2.3-1~38~precise1 1000
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     1.4.1-1ppa0~precise 1000
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/nginx/stable/ubuntu/ precise/main amd64 Packages
     1.1.19-1ubuntu0.1 1000
        500 http://mirror.rackspace.co.uk/ubuntu/ precise-updates/universe amd64 Packages
     1.1.19-1 1000
        500 http://mirror.rackspace.co.uk/ubuntu/ precise/universe amd64 Packages
```

Anyone has any idea how to achieve what I'm trying to do ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Here is an example of `/etc/apt/preferences`

```
mint@mint ~ $ cat /etc/apt/preferences
Package: *
Pin: release o=linuxmint
Pin-Priority: 700

Package: *
Pin: origin packages.linuxmint.com
Pin-Priority: 700

Package: *
Pin: release o=Ubuntu
Pin-Priority: 500
```

You probably have to run `apt-get update` after creating the file.

Comment: /etc/apt/preferences doesn't exist on 13.04, although /etc/apt/preferences.d/ exists, but is an empty directory.

Comment: The file is not stock you just create it

Answer (score 4):

Short answer: Set pinning-priority to less than 0 and set o=LP-PPA-*, e.g.

```
Package: nginx-full
Pin: release o=LP-PPA-brightbox-ruby-ng-experimental
Pin-Priority: -10
```

Quote from apt_preferences-manpage:

```
How APT Interprets Priorities
...
P < 0
prevents the version from being installed
```

Further information:
http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/raring/en/man5/apt_preferences.5.html and  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PinningHowto.