# Get latest version of package when not available for current distro

Tags: upgrade, package-management, updates

Basically, I have this:

```
lucho@lucho-HP:~$ apt-cache policy dynare-matlab
dynare-matlab:
  Installed: 4.4.1-1build1
  Candidate: 4.4.1-1build1
  Version table:
     4.4.3-1~trusty1 0
        100 http://www.dynare.org/ubuntu/ trusty/contrib amd64 Packages
 *** 4.4.1-1build1 0
        500 mirror://mirrors.ubuntu.com/mirrors.txt/ trusty/multiverse amd64 Packages
        500 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/multiverse amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Yet, apt-get upgrade **won't** upgrade from 4.4.1 to 4.4.3. Given my limited knowledge of `upgrade` and `dist-upgrade`, the former is not upgrading because some other packages need to be installed/removed (i.e I need to update distro from 14.04 to ...?). So, without updating distro, is there any way to get the latest package working?

Answer (score 1):

Simple way:

```
apt-get install dynare-matlab=4.4.3-1~trusty1
```

Best way: Using priority like:

[Assign higher priority to PPA](https://askubuntu.com/questions/293619/assign-higher-priority-to-ppa)

Comment: This might work. Notice that I want to upgrade the package, not reinstall it. Will this command upgrade the package? There is no info related to this in the apt-get manual.

Comment: Nothing happens. I get `The following extra packages will be installed:`\\
  `dynare-matlab`\\
`0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 14 not to upgrade.`\\
`lucho@lucho-HP:~$`