# Prioritizing PPA

Tags: 14.04, apt, package-management, ppa

I am using Travis-CI which uses an Ubuntu 14.04 Trusty VM to run a script. In order to run correctly the script requires the package `protobuf-compiler` version 3+ and the corresponding `libprotobuf-dev` package to be installed. Unfortunately doing the obvious `apt-get install protobuf-compiler libprotobuf-dev` gives me version 2.5 which is too old to compile the script.

Fortunately [there is a PPA](https://launchpad.net/~maarten-fonville/+archive/ubuntu/protobuf) that provides version 3.4 for Trusty. I used `add-apt-repository ppa:maarten-fonville/protobuf` to add the PPA with the appropriate `apt-get update` but I still got the old version from `archive.ubuntu.com`, not the PPA version.

I tried giving the PPA a higher priority using [this `/etc/apt/preferences` file](https://github.com/Toeger/SCE/blob/ce32d25e8313739c9ff9580a65b101e1979ceeff/preferences) as described [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/293619/assign-higher-priority-to-ppa) but I still got version 2.5.

There is a [log of my script](https://travis-ci.org/Toeger/SCE/builds/333365881) with the commands used. Line 506 adds the PPA, line 615 copies the `preferences` file, line 617 makes the `apt update` and line 719 installs the (incorrect) packages. Unfolding line 7 shows various system information.

How do I install `protobuf-compiler` version 3+ on Ubuntu Trusty?

Comment: davidbaumann mentioned that `protobuf-compiler` was available [here](http://ppa.launchpad.net/maarten-fonville/protobuf/ubuntu/pool/main/p/protobuf/).

Comment: @ChaiT.Rex How do I use that? Do I `wget` the `.dep` and then `dpkg -i` it? I though `add-apt-repository ppa:maarten-fonville/protobuf` would essentially make those `.dep` files available to `apt` which then handles the rest.

Comment: I'm not sure why that PPA doesn't work on 14.04. It works here on 16.04. I think that you just install it with `sudo apt-get install ./whatever.deb`.

Comment: [This page](https://launchpad.net/~maarten-fonville/+archive/ubuntu/protobuf/+packages) suggests the package for trusty failed to build, so it makes some sense that it works on 16.04 and fails on 14.04.

Comment: The package provider updated the package to build in trusty, so the PPA works now without any preference hackery.

Answer (score 0):

The package is available from the mentioned PPA as of yesterday (1/27/18) from http://ppa.launchpad.net/maarten-fonville/protobuf/ubuntu/pool/main/p/protobuf/ for both the 64-bit and 32-bit versions of trusty. I'm not sure why `protobuf-compiler` doesn't show as being available on [the launchpad page.](https://launchpad.net/~maarten-fonville/+archive/ubuntu/protobuf?field.series_filter=trusty)

However `sudo apt install protobuf-compiler` will install it and it's dependencies from the PPA. I believe the aforementioned dependencies specifically `libprotobuf15` and `libprotoc15` are the reason why it wouldn't install standalone with `dpkg -i` if downloaded directly from http://ppa.launchpad.net/maarten-fonville/protobuf/ubuntu/pool/main/p/protobuf/protobuf-compiler_3.5.1.1-0~maarten0+trusty0_amd64.deb

Sources:

Testing

@nwp [comment here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/999871/prioritizing-ppa#comment1617527_999871)