# How do I specify the repository `apt-get` pulls from when installing (e.g. Kdenlive)

Tags: apt, software-installation, repository, kdenlive

I added the "Kdenlive" team PPA to my Ubuntu 18.04 system as [described at this link here](https://launchpad.net/%7Ekdenlive/+archive/ubuntu/kdenlive-stable).

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:kdenlive/kdenlive-stable
sudo apt-get update
```

Then I installed Kdenlive via `sudo apt-get install kdenlive`. I opened Kdenlive and noticed that I was on Kdenlive version `17.12.3`, not the latest version `20.04.0` that's in the ppa I just added.

What command can I use to force Ubuntu to grab the PPA version of kdenlive (or whatever program I happen to be installing), instead of grabbing from the generic repository, which is what I think is happening in my case.

I thought that the `sudo apt-get update` command was supposed to force Ubuntu to grab things from the "newest" repository. My assumptions appear off. I should also add that if I search `Kdenlive` in Ubuntu Software Center both `17.12.3` and `20.04.0` show as installable options (and a Flathub version). All three are separate entries in the Software Center. Searching in Synaptic doesn't show these same three options (only one Kdenlive is listed).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Recommended way to install Kdenlive on Ubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1056373/recommended-way-to-install-kdenlive-on-ubuntu-18-04)

Comment: @N0rbert He said in this question that the question didn't help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

APT fetches the packages from repositories on the basis of version, if no priority is defined in `/etc/apt/preferences`. It seems the PPA Kdenlive is *merely* a dummy PPA for releases older than 19.10 since [their PPA page](https://launchpad.net/%7Ekdenlive/+archive/ubuntu/kdenlive-stable) on Launchpad doesn't have details for still supported release such as 16.04 (Xenial Xerus) and 18.04 (Bionic Beaver). Moreover, the [Packages file](http://ppa.launchpad.net/kdenlive/kdenlive-stable/ubuntu/dists/bionic/main/binary-amd64/Packages.xz) for Bionic is empty and there is no debian package for the release in [/pool](http://ppa.launchpad.net/kdenlive/kdenlive-stable/ubuntu/pool/main/k/kdenlive/) as well.

If you run `apt-cache policy kdenlive`, you may notice that this package is being provided by official Ubuntu repositories out of all repositories configured. So, in a nutshell, you're *installing latest available* version.

**Related Posts:**

- [Assign higher priority to PPA](https://askubuntu.com/q/293619/816190)
- [How to see all packages in a package repository? Website or command line?](https://askubuntu.com/q/1210473/816190)